# npm install doesn't save dependency to package.json

Tags: node.js, npm

It does add only when I execute: `npm install <package_name> --save`

In the documentation though: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/install is written this:

> By default, npm install will install all modules listed as dependencies in package.json.

Which is misleading.

Comment: By default, npm install will install all modules *'already'* listed as dependencies in package.json. 'npm install <package>' will never write back to package.json unless you use '--save'

Answer (score 30, accepted):

`npm install` without arguments installs all dependencies (and dev dependencies) listed in the `package.json` file.

`npm install --production` installs all the dependencies (but no dev dependency)

`npm install <package>` installs a package and its dependencies.

`npm install <package> --save` installs a package and its dependencies, and adds it in the `package.json` file.

**Edit:** Since npm 5, `--save` is implied.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not. I think you are misreading the sentence.

`npm install` without any package name (as in your quote) will install all dependencies mentioned in the package.json.

Comment: Except, when it doesn't. I've been trying all day to get my perfectly defined package.json files to install.

Answer (score 0):

Crete package.json file in your application folder.

Exp:- var/www/html/node/rest/package.json

{
    "name": "node-api",
    "main": "server.js",
    "version": "0.0.1",
    "dependencies": {
        "express": "~4.0.0",
        "mongoose": "~3.6.13",
        "body-parser": "~1.0.1",
        "mysql": "^2.5.4"
    }
}

Then run npm install command your application folder

Exp:- var/www/html/node/rest    npm install

Answer (score 0):

You could run `npm init` again to update the dependencies info.